# From a Logical Point of View quote, 2nd and 1st editions

Tags: philosophy-of-science, quote

I have access to the quote

> The analogy between the myth of mathematics and the myth of physics is, in some additional and perhaps fortuitous ways, strikingly close. Consider, for example, the crisis which was precipitated in the foundations of mathematics, at the turn of the century, by the discovery of Russell’s paradox and other antinomies of set theory. These contradictions had to be obviated by unintuitive, ad hoc devices; our mathematical myth-making became deliberate and evident to all. But, what, of physics? An antinomy arose between the undular and the corpuscular accounts of light; and if this was not as out-and-out a contradiction as Russell’s paradox, I suspect that the reason is that physics is not as out-and-out as mathematics.
> Blockquote

from pages 18-19 in the 1st chapter of the **Second edition** of Willard van Orman Quine's book *From a Logical Point of View.*

What is the pagination of the quote in the **First edition** of Quine's book?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ?

Comment: Sorry, I've the 2nd edition :-)